# How to create a dynamic proxy of a already proxyed class in spring

Tags: java, proxy, spring-cloud, feign, resilience4j

I'm relativly new to spring/spring boot.

At the moment I'm using a spring boot rest application which provides an FeignClient to be included in other projects. Now, I want those FeignClients be wrapped by a CircuitBreaker.

The best solution I came up with, is that I dynamically create a proxy which includes the CircuitBreaker implementation which itself calls the created FeignClient.

So let's assume I have the following interface which describes the RestController:

```java
@RequestMapping("/")
public interface MyWebService {

    @GetMapping("name")
    public String getName();
}
```

Now, I have the interface for the FeignClient:

```java
@FeignClient("app")
public interface WebServiceClient extends WebService {
}
```

So.. My goal would be to achieve something like I have another annotation e. g. `@WithCircuitBreaker` which I then will be scanned for and dynamically create a proxy bean which will be injected instead of the FeignClient bean.

At the moment my code looks like this:

```java
@FeignClient("app")
@WithCircuitBreaker
public interface WebServiceClient extends WebService {
}
```

As far as I know, I can now create a `@Configuration` Class which will look like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class WithCircuitBreakerConfiguration implements ImportAware {

    private AnnotationMetadata annotationMetadata;
    private AnnotationAttributes annotationAttributes;

    @Override
    public void setImportMetadata(AnnotationMetadata importMetadata) {
        this.annotationMetadata = importMetadata;
        Map<String, Object> annotatedClasses = importMetadata.getAnnotationAttributes(WithCircuitBreaker.class.getName());
        this.annotationAttributes = AnnotationAttributes.fromMap(annotatedClasses);
    }

    What else to import to create the proxy and inject it?
}
```

Now I'm at the point, which I don't know how to continue. How to dynamically create a proxy class which does something like this:

```java
public class PorxyedWebService {

    private WebService feignClientProxy;

    @Autowired
    public ProxyedWebService(WebService feignClientProxy) {
        this.feignClientProxy = feignClientProxy;
    }

    public String getName() {
        ...
        <some circuitbreaker stuff>
        ....
        return this.feignClientProxy.getName();
    }
}
```

and then return this proxy instead of the proxy generated from Feign as soon as someone autowires the `WebService` interface.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a Spring user, but I do know that Spring does **not** create proxies recursively if e.g. multiple Spring AOP aspects are applied to the same object. Instead, additional interceptors (or advices in AOP language) are registered upon the same proxy. I think you want to use that infrastructure in order to achieve whatever your objective is.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the resilience4j Spring Boot2 starter.
You can combine the `@CircuitBreaker` annotation with the `@FeignClient` annotation at interface level.

You can then use it as follows:

```
@FeignClient(name = DUMMY_FEIGN_CLIENT_NAME)
@CircuitBreaker(name = DUMMY_FEIGN_CLIENT_NAME)
public interface DummyFeignClient {

    String DUMMY_FEIGN_CLIENT_NAME = "dummyFeignClient";

    @GetMapping(path = "/api/{param}")
    void doSomething(@PathVariable(name = "param") String param);
}
```